# How to change macro to replace \begin{theorem} ... \end{theorem} by \theorem?

Tags: macros, preamble, shortcut

To state a theorem, what we do usually :

```
\begin{theorem}

... (statement) ...

\end{theorem}
```

I want to change the macro so that I can use `\theorem` like `\section`:

```
\theorem

... (statement) ...
```

Is it possible do be done? We could have used definition/lemma/proposition in place of theorem (I use amsclass documentclass).

Comment: But how would you tell LaTeX where such theorem ends?

Comment: Good point. How about
\theorem{... (statement) ...}?

Comment: What I want is to minimize latexing effort. Any suggestion regarding this is very much welcome.

Comment: Depending on the editor you are using the "minimization of effort" will be minimal. With the editor I use I save 5 keystrokes when using the second alternative, with the downside of not having the code syntax-highlighted. Believe me, it looks like you are "minimizing" effort, but this is generally not a good idea.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Define your theorem with a different name:

```
\newtheorem{theoremx}{Theorem}
```

then do

```
\newcommand{\theorem}[1]{\begin{theoremx}#1\end{theoremx}}
```

Now compare

```
\begin{theoremx}
This is the statement.
\end{theoremx}
```

with

```
\theorem{This is the statement.}
```

and decide whether this is worthy the effort.

If you decide to pursue this strategy (I definitely don't recommend it), you can do

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentCommand{\newargumenttheorem}{momo}
 {
  \NewDocumentCommand{#1}{om}
   {
    \IfValueTF{##1}
     {
      \begin{\cs_to_str:N #1-inner}[##1] ##2 \end{\cs_to_str:N #1-inner}
     }
     {
      \begin{\cs_to_str:N #1-inner} ##2 \end{\cs_to_str:N #1-inner}
     }
   }
  \IfValueTF{#2}
   {
    \newtheorem{\cs_to_str:N #1-inner}[#2-inner]{#3}
   }
   {
    \IfValueTF{#4}
     {
      \newtheorem{\cs_to_str:N #1-inner}{#3}[#4]
     }
     {
      \newtheorem{\cs_to_str:N #1-inner}{#3}
     }
   }
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\newargumenttheorem{\theorem}{Theorem}[section]
\newargumenttheorem{\lemma}[theorem]{Lemma}
\newargumenttheorem{\definition}{Definition}

\begin{document}

\section{Test}

\definition{This is a definition.}

\lemma{This is a lemma.}

\theorem[Important]{\label{important}This is a theorem.}

Theorem \ref{important} is very important.

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The `theorem` environment, like many other LaTeX environments, already has a macro `\theorem`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}

\begin{document}
\section{Introduction}
Theorems can easily be defined

\theorem {
Let $f$ be a function whose derivative exists in every point, then $f$ 
is a continuous function.
}

\end{document}
```

Edit:

Another option which avoids the problem noted out by @PhelypeOleinik:

```
\documentclass{article}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}

\let\oldtheorem\theorem
\let\endoldtheorem\endtheorem
\renewcommand\theorem[1]{\begin{oldtheorem}#1\end{oldtheorem}}

\begin{document}
\section{Introduction}
Theorems can easily be defined

\theorem {
Let $f$ be a function whose derivative exists in every point, then $f$ 
is a continuous function.
} 

Let $f$ be a function whose derivative exists in every point, then $f$ 
is a continuous function

\end{document}
```

> [image]

Comment: Try to add some text after the `\theorem`...

Answer (score 0):

To answer to the version you stated in the comments you could simply do it like this:

```
\newcommand{\mytheorem}[1]{\begin{theorem}#1\end{theorem}}
```

That should do it. It's not tested though.

Comment: You could do something to deal with the optional argument of `\begin{theorem}`.